# HTML: Span shows missing text

Tags: html, css, angular

Using Angular, I am trying to show list of strings as a paragraph "inline". In my html part I have:

```
<p>
<span *ngFor="let ayah of surah.ayat">{{ayah.text_For_Html}}</span>
</p>
```

For some reason the long paragraphs (100+ in the ngFor loop), the text shows missing parts. For example without span and using div I get:
[image]

but when I use span like in the code I showed before I get for the same text:
[image]

The text shows missing parts of it (In the example it skipped over 10 strings in the beginning), and I confirmed that these missing/hidden spans are in the Elements using Chrome's inspect. Also, I think it's worth to mention that I am using Arabic and an Arabic font for Quran. Please anyone can enlighten me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you need the span tags for styling? Otherwise you should be able to use an `<ng-container>` to bind the `*ngFor` directive to, and you should end up with a paragraph tag with just the text.

Comment: I used <span> to make the text inline to from a big paragraph... It breaks when I do, shows the correct form when it's not inline and it's blocks

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like it might be CSS-related.